# Ring with certain properties is a Direct Sum of certain types of matrices. What this is process called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have read some articles/papers where authors have proved that a *ring with certain properties is a direct sum of certain types of matrices*. I suppose an author is proving that such a ring is just a ring of certain types of matrices.

**Question**: In general what do we call the above process? Characterizing a ring? Or what else?

Comment: Direct sum decomposition?  A ring can be a direct sum of two (or more) rings.  Also some rings can be represented as rings whose elements are added and multiplied as matrices are.  So you seem to have two kinds of (important) ideas on your mind.

Comment: I think I would call it something like "describing the structure of a ring". I don't think it has a name. It's just answering the question "what the hell *is* this thing?".